# Finding the maximum of an exponential sum

Tags: derivatives, optimization, exponential-function, approximation, exponential-sum

my problem is how to find the maximum of an exponential sum. The interested function is $f(x)=\sum^M_{m=1}\exp(a_mx^2+b_mx+c_m)$. $a_m$, $b_m$ and $c_m$ for all $m$ are known coefficients and $M$ is known as well.

However, finding the maximum of $f(x)$ seems not straightforward as it is not a monotone function. If trying to find the roots of $\text{d}f(x)/\text{d}x$ and obtain the extrema, it seems still can not be done.

My anther idea is to use exponential series to approximate $f(x)$, like $e^x=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$, and do the derivative. However, the maximum or extrema still not can be found.

Does anyone has suggestion to solve this problem? By using approximation, semi-analytical method or some else?

Thank you.

Comment: Is Newton's method an acceptable solution? Or bisection search on the derivative?

Comment: Thanks. It is exactly what I am so far reaching. It can find the maximum and minimum points in a numerical way. I would like to seek a analytical expression for x, which can not be obtained via most search techniques.

Comment: AFAIK we can't even write down the solution to $\exp(a_1 x + b_1) + \exp(a_2 x + b_2) + \exp(a_3 x + b_3) = 0$, so there is almost certainly no closed-form representation for the quantity you're looking for.

Comment: Truly. I have been aware of that now. Thank you anyway.